# Is this way of associated sorting safe to use?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays. The first contains words, second - their weights. They are associated by indices. How i can sort these arrays by second array, maintaining the association?

Here's what I've attempted:

```js
let words = [
  'car',
  'house',
  'sky',
  'dog',
  'wheel',
  'man',
  'tree',
  'earth'
];

let weights = [
  10,
  43,
  23,
  95,
  55,
  41,
  29,
  84
];

let memory = [];

weights.sort((a, b) => {
  memory.push(b - a);
  return memory[memory.length - 1];
});

words.sort(() => memory.shift());

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  console.log(words[i], weights[i]);
}
```

It seems to be working correctly. But I'm afraid that it might not work. Is this way theoretically correct?

**Attention!** I'm not asking you to fix my algorithm. I ask you, to speak out about the possible errors of such sorting.

Comment: Why not just make one array of objects with keys like `word` and `weight`? Not only would that make your code clearer, but it is also guaranteed to work correctly

Comment: Yes you are right. This can be done in another way. And it is known to me. I'm not asking for help in optimizing my algorithm. I wonder if it will work properly. And that's all.

Comment: Yes, you should be afraid that it might not work. You cannot assume that the sort algorithm will always be the same.

Comment: Why not? If both arrays are of the same length, then the sorting algorithm can hardly depend on the data. Rather, only from the result of comparison.

Comment: you mimic the same return values for the second sorting. this is kind of clever, and may work, but it is a bit stange and unusual for later understanding.

Comment: Something like what I wanted to hear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array with the indices of `weights` and sort it with the value of the index and map the result by taking the sorted index array.

Basically this is a [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map).

```js
var words = ['car', 'house', 'sky', 'dog', 'wheel', 'man', 'tree', 'earth'],
    weights = [10, 43, 23, 95, 55, 41, 29, 84],
    temp = weights
        .map((_, i) => i)
        .sort((a, b) => weights[b] - weights[a]),
    result_words = temp.map(i => words[i]),
    result_weights = temp.map(i => weights[i]);

console.log(result_words.map((a, i) => [a, result_weights[i]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Need to print along with the words and their weight

Answer (score 0):

You can use index of current words elements in sort and then sort by value of element from weights with same index.

```js
let words = ["car", "house", "sky", "dog", "wheel", "man", "tree", "earth"]
let weights = [ 10, 43, 23, 95, 55, 41, 29, 84 ]

var result = words
  .map((e, i) => e + ' ' + weights[i])
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    var a = a.split(' ').shift(), b = b.split(' ').shift()
    return weights[words.indexOf(b)] - weights[words.indexOf(a)]
  })

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You do not sort both arrays